# MS Access Error - Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed

Tags: ms-access, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, vba, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure in MS SQL Server 2012 from MS Access 2007. I have added Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library as a reference.
Here's my VBA code:

```
Function Sproc()
    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim cnnStr As String
    Dim Rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim StrSproc As String

    cnnStr = "Provider=test\SQL2012;Data Source=DBSource;" & "Initial Catalog=test;" & _
             "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    With cnn
        .CommandTimeout = 900
        .ConnectionString = cnnStr
        .Open
    End With
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = cnn
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = "[test]"
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@ID", adInteger, adParamInput, , Me.ID)
    End With
    With Rs
        .CursorType = adOpenStatic
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
        .Open cmd
    End With
    Set rst = cmd.Execute
End Function
```

When I run the function I get the following error

[image: Error message]

Any kind of help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a valid provider. The provider is **not** the name of the database.

Depending on what you've got installed, different providers may be available. The `sqloledb` provider is a common one.

```
cnnStr = "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=test\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=DBSource;" & _
         "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```